# Determining the number of elements of order $n$ in a finite group which has $k$ cyclic subgroups of order $n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $n,k$ be positive integers and let $G$ be a group which has $k$ cyclic subgroups of order $n$. Determine with proof the number of elements of order $n$ in $G$.

For example, a finite group $G$ which has $28$ cyclic subgroups of order $4$ has $56$ elements of order $4$.

Thanks so much for taking your time!

Comment: You mean $k\varphi(n)$?

Comment: @Sean, did you really grasp the *proof* given the hint of Alex Youcis and his correct answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: In any cyclic subgroup of order $n$, there are $\varphi(n)$ generators.

Answer (score 0):

$k\cdot\varphi  (n) $, because they can't share any generators (or they'd be the same group).